# How to find nearest non-holiday, non-weekend date by subtracting one day at a time?

Tags: php, date, oop, recursion, decrement

I have arrays of objects like:

```
$holiday_calendar = Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [holiday] => New Year\'s Day
            [holidayDate] => 2018-01-01
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [holiday] => Republic Day
            [holidayDate] => 2018-01-26
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [holiday] => Holi
            [holidayDate] => 2018-03-02
        )
)

$payroll_days_list = Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [payrollDay] => Mon
            [isPayrollDay] => Y
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [payrollDay] => Tue
            [isPayrollDay] => Y
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [payrollDay] => Wed
            [isPayrollDay] => Y
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [payrollDay] => Thu
            [isPayrollDay] => Y
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [payrollDay] => Fri
            [isPayrollDay] => Y
        )

    [5] => stdClass Object
        (
            [payrollDay] => Sat
            [isPayrollDay] => N
        )

    [6] => stdClass Object
        (
            [payrollDay] => Sun
            [isPayrollDay] => N
        )

)
```

I need to check if the given date is not a holiday and is not a Sat or Sun.

If the date falls on a holiday or on Sat or Sun, the date should be moved back one day at a time until it falls on a qualifying date.

I have written this code:

```
$dt = "04/03/2018";

echo $dt = $this->checkHolidayExists($dt, $holiday_calendar, $payroll_days_list);

function checkHolidayExists($dt, $holiday_calendar, $payroll_days_list) {
    if (empty($holiday_calendar) && empty($payroll_days_list)) {
        return $dt;
    } else {
        foreach ($holiday_calendar as $hc) {
            if ($hc->holidayDate == $dt) {
                $dt = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($dt . ' -1 days'));
                $this->checkHolidayExists($dt, $holiday_calendar, $payroll_days_list);
            }
        }

        foreach ($payroll_days_list as $pdl) {
            if ($pdl->payrollDay == date('D', strtotime($dt)) && $pdl->isPayrollDay == 'N') {
                $dt = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($dt . ' -1 days'));
                $this->checkHolidayExists($dt, $holiday_calendar, $payroll_days_list);
            }
        }
        return $dt;
    }
}
```

But this returns a date of `03/03/2018`.

It should be `01/03/2018` because the 4th is Sunday, the 3rd is Saturday, the 2nd is a holiday.

Please let me know what I'm missing.

Comment: your recursive call should be `$dt=$this->check...`, otherwise the return value of the second call is unused, and you still return the `$dt` value from the first check

Comment: didn't you forgot the `$dt =` in your 2 foreach => `$dt = $this->check....` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to fill in some of the missing components, but perhaps you can glean the necessary logic from my re-write.  My class endeavors to minimize recursion by reversing the order of the disqualifying object arrays.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/amkvS))

```
class PayDay
{
    public function __construct($Ymd = null) {
        $this->date = $Ymd ?: date("Y-m-d");

        $this->holiday_calendar = [
            (object)["holiday" => "New Year's Day", "holidayDate" => "2018-01-01"],
            (object)["holiday" => "Republic Day", "holidayDate" => "2018-01-26"],
            (object)["holiday" => "Holi", "holidayDate" => "2018-03-02"]
        ];

        $this->payroll_days_list = [
            (object)["payrollDay" => "Mon", "isPayrollDay" => "Y"],
            (object)["payrollDay" => "Tue", "isPayrollDay" => "Y"],
            (object)["payrollDay" => "Wed", "isPayrollDay" => "Y"],
            (object)["payrollDay" => "Thu", "isPayrollDay" => "Y"],
            (object)["payrollDay" => "Fri", "isPayrollDay" => "Y"],
            (object)["payrollDay" => "Sat", "isPayrollDay" => "N"],
            (object)["payrollDay" => "Sun", "isPayrollDay" => "N"]
        ];

        echo "Starting Date: ",$this->date,"\n";
    }

    public function getPayDate() {
        $hc_match = false;
        foreach (array_reverse($this->holiday_calendar) as $hc) {  // work in reverse to reduce recursions
            if ($hc->holidayDate == $this->date) {
                $hc_match = true;
                //echo "Avoided: ", $hc->holiday,"\n";
                $this->loseOneDay();
                //echo "New Date: ", $this->date,"\n";
            } elseif ($hc_match) {                            // break when consecutive adjustments cease, to reduce recursions
                break;
            }
        }

        $pdl_match = false;
        foreach (array_reverse($this->payroll_days_list) as $pdl) {  // work in reverse to reduce recursions
            if ($pdl->payrollDay == date("D", strtotime($this->date)) && $pdl->isPayrollDay == "N") {
                $pdl_match = true;
                //echo "Avoided: ", $pdl->payrollDay,"\n";
                $this->loseOneDay();
                //echo "New Date: ", $this->date,"\n";
            } elseif ($pdl_match) {                           // break when consecutive adjustments cease, to reduce recursions
                break;
            }
        }

        if ($hc_match || $pdl_match) {
            //echo "\tRECURSE\n";
            $this->getPayDate();
        }
        return $this->date;
    }

    public function loseOneDay(){
        return $this->date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($this->date." -1 day"));
    }
}

$date = new PayDay("2018-03-04");
echo "Adjusted Date: ", $date->getPayDate();
```

Output:

```
Starting Date: 2018-03-04
Adjusted Date: 2018-03-01
```

Be sure to make your date formats uniform throughout so that you don't have `04/03/2018` being compared against `2018-03-04`.  Of course, the format is up to you, just pick one for `$dt` and `$this->holiday_calendar->holidayDate` for simplicity's sake.

As for your posted code, because your `foreach()` loops don't incorporate a `break`, you are doing extra/unnecessary iterations after a match was found.

I'll recommend iterating the arrays of objects in reverse (or even better would be to declare them in reverse) so that you can perform consecutive adjustment in the same function call.

---

After a little more thought, I think I'd probably work with DateTime objects and take the time to prepare the disqualifying data to streamline the iterative date adjusting process.  The following class doesn't use recursion at all, but a dual-condition loop.  (Again, how you import your disqualifying object arrays is up to you.)

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/UMUY7))

```
class PayDay
{
    public function __construct($dmY = null) {
        $this->date = (is_null($dmY) ? new DateTime("midnight") : DateTime::createFromFormat('!d/m/Y', $dmY));  // ! for midnight

        $holiday_calendar = [                                          // import this data however you wish
            (object)["holiday" => "New Year's Day", "holidayDate" => "2018-01-01"],
            (object)["holiday" => "Republic Day", "holidayDate" => "2018-01-26"],
            (object)["holiday" => "Holi", "holidayDate" => "2018-03-02"]
        ];
        $this->blacklist_holidates = [];
        if (!empty($holiday_calendar)) {
            foreach ($holiday_calendar as $obj) {
                $this->blacklist_holidates[$obj->holiday] = DateTime::createFromFormat('!Y-m-d', $obj->holidayDate);  // ! for midnight
            }
        }

        $payroll_days_list = [                                          // import this data however you wish
            (object)["payrollDay" => "Mon", "isPayrollDay" => "Y"],
            (object)["payrollDay" => "Tue", "isPayrollDay" => "Y"],
            (object)["payrollDay" => "Wed", "isPayrollDay" => "Y"],
            (object)["payrollDay" => "Thu", "isPayrollDay" => "Y"],
            (object)["payrollDay" => "Fri", "isPayrollDay" => "Y"],
            (object)["payrollDay" => "Sat", "isPayrollDay" => "N"],
            (object)["payrollDay" => "Sun", "isPayrollDay" => "N"]
        ];
        $this->blacklist_daynames = [];
        if (!empty($payroll_days_list)) {
            foreach ($payroll_days_list as $obj) {
                if ($obj->isPayrollDay == "N") {
                    $this->blacklist_daynames[] = $obj->payrollDay;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public function getPayDate() {
        while (in_array($this->date, $this->blacklist_holidates) || in_array($this->date->format("D"), $this->blacklist_daynames)) {
            $this->date->sub(new DateInterval('P1D'));
        }
        return $this->date->format("d/m/Y");
    }
}

$input = "04/03/2018";
echo "Starting Date: $input\n";
$date = new PayDay($input);
echo "Qualifying PayDate: ",$date->getPayDate();
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks for answer. I cannot use array_reverse because calendar array can have holidays till year end. I just added few for example.
But as i implemented your logic (with some changes), still i'm getting wrong result (03/03/2018) than expected (01/03/2018)

Comment: function checkHolidayExists($dt, $holiday_calendar, $payroll_days_list) {
    $hc_match = false;
    foreach ($holiday_calendar as $hc) {
 if ($hc->holidayDate == $dt) {
     $hc_match = true;
     $dt = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($dt . ' -1 days'));
 } elseif ($hc_match) {
     break;
 }
    }

Comment: $pdl_match = false;
    foreach ($payroll_days_list as $pdl) {
    if ($pdl->payrollDay == date("D", strtotime($dt)) && $pdl->isPayrollDay == "N") {
     $pdl_match = true;
     $dt = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($dt . ' -1 days'));
 } elseif ($pdl_match) {
     break;
 }
    }

    if ($hc_match || $pdl_match) {
 $this->checkHolidayExists($dt, $holiday_calendar, $payroll_days_list);
    }
    return $dt;
}

Comment: Please can you check above code split in 2 comments and let me know the issue. I need to follow same logic as it is some part of my code.

Comment: Keep in mind that I am standardizing the date format as `Y-m-d` for my usage because your Holiday dates are in that format.  I'd like to say that it is rather inappropriate data storage to have different date formats to bounce around between.

Comment: `strtotime()` will break when you try to feed it `d/m/Y`  when using slashes, it expects `m/d/Y` (American-style) https://3v4l.org/FDYL6  If you want to keep your `d m Y` digit order, you can call `str_replace('/','-',$dt)` to generate `d-m-Y` strings.  Or of course you can fully remove your `strtotime()` dependency and use a [Datetime class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php).

Comment: `str_reverse()` is only called to reduce the number of recursions.  Your holiday can't really be THAT long right?  Probably not more than ~30 I'd guess.  My method will work without `array_reverse()` anyhow.  Unless your program _needs_ the flexibility, I'd suggest hardcoding `Sat` and `Sun` as non-business days and spare the data storage and iterated checking.

Comment: @GaneshGadge Here is another version that will receive your `d/m/Y` date formatted input and output the result in the same format.  Frankly the date handling is clunky.  You should determine a single date format for all data in the process.  https://3v4l.org/bG51h

Comment: @GaneshGadge I thought I'd let you know that I've reconsidered my class and added an alternative class structure to my answer.  This leverages DateTime objects and a simple while loop instead of recursion. Now you can choose the type of design structure that you prefer.